# Retrieve last sent mail from Gmail using Javamail

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

I am trying to get the last sent mail in Gmail using Javamail api. Here is the code -

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");

try{
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imap");
    store.connect(mailbox, mailId, passwod);

    sent  = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
    int totalSentMails = sent.getMessageCount();

    sent.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);


    Message sentmesage = sent.getMessage(totalSentMails);
}
catch (NoSuchProviderException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
}
```

Since the getMessage count returns a number which is much greater than the actual mails i get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

How can i get the exact number of sent mails from Gmail using javamail api ?
The error i get is -

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1986 > 1970
```

1986 is the value of totalSentMails fetched above and 1970 is the actual number of sent mails

Comment: Can u post your full code and the error here??

Comment: A [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) would be really helpful.

Comment: oops my mistake. was trying to get the sent messages count before opening the folder. But what i dont understand is before opening it was giving a count of 1986 (wrong) and after opening it gives the correct count i.e 1971.

Comment: thanks Dan! open() has to be invoked before getMessagesCount() is called

Comment: Hi , my cod is similar to the yours, and I am also using folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE); Still I am getting IndxOutOfBoundException.8363>8358

Answer (score 1):

**

### Use this code to read the gmail Sent mail folder,Draft,Important,starred,Spam,Trash,Inbox,All Mail

**

```
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore();
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "gmailpassword");
        Folder[] folderList = store.getFolder("[Gmail]").list();
        for (int i = 0; i < folderList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(folderList[i].getFullName());
        }
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
        Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
        for (Address address : in) {
            System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
        }
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
        BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
        System.out.println("Bcc User NAme :"+InternetAddress.toString(msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC)));
        System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
        System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
        System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());
    } catch (Exception mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code working perfectly guys..Enjoy:)

Comment: The folder name seems to have changed from "[Gmail]" (throws exception) to "[Google Mail]". See: http://tinybrain.de/1003300

Comment: This is working properly :)